# Is Joan's pigpio rotary Encoder C library callable from python ctypes?

Tags: python, c, pigpio

I'm using Python class [Rotary Encoder](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#Python_rotary_encoder_py) to implement a Position PI on a [stepper motor](https://www.ebay.com/itm/US-Free-Ship-3Axis-Nema34-Stepper-Motor-Single-Shaft-1600oz-in-Driver-CNC-kit-/303219117857?oid=151340545611) and using this encoder [H6BM-1000-500-IE-S-H](http://www.usdigital.com/products/encoders/incremental/rotary/hollow-bore/hb6m)

The code is working quite well, however I'm getting an error of ~5mm when I run large distances. My guess is that I'm missing interrupts because of speed, however my whole code is on Python. I wanted to know if I could use [this C code](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#pdif2_RED) via ctypes to wrap it to Python. I'm new to this Python module (ctypes) and don't use C at all. If it is possible, how should I compile it in order to use it on Python?

It doesn't have to be exclusively the C code mentioned above, but preferably pigpio code.

It can also be this [C code](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#C_rotary_encoder_c) for Rotary Encoder.

Answer (score 1):

I use the roatary_encooder driver.
https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/input/rotary-encoder.txt

It has device tree bindings here:
http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/input/rotary-encoder.txt

My dts(device tree source) is:

```
/*
 * wheelhat-overlay.dts
 */

/dts-v1/;
/plugin/;

/ {
    compatible = "brcm,bcm2835", "brcm,bcm2708", "brcm,bcm2709";

    fragment@0 {
        target-path = "/soc/gpio";
        __overlay__ {
            wheel_pins: wheel_pins {
                brcm,pins = <13 27>;
                brcm,function = <0>;
                brcm,pull = <2>;
            };
        };
    };

    fragment@1 {
        target-path = "/soc";
        __overlay__ {
            wheel: wheel {
                compatible = "rotary-encoder";
                #address-cells = <1>;
                #size-cells = <0>;
                pinctrl-names = "default";
                pinctrl-0 = <&wheel_pins>;
                gpios = <&gpio 13 1>, <&gpio 27 1>; 
                linux,axis = <0>; /* REL_X */
                rotary-encoder,relative-axis;
            };
        };
    };
    __overrides__ {
        relative_axis =  <&wheel>,"rotary-encoder,relative-axis";
        linux_axis =  <&wheel>,"linux,axis";
        rollover =  <&wheel>,"rotary-encoder,rollover";
        half-period =  <&wheel>,"rotary-encoder,half-period";
        steps =  <&wheel>,"rotary-encoder,steps";
    };
};
```

The first fragment makes the pins have an input function with a pull-up. The rest is configuration and names exported to `/boot/config.txt`. You compile the DTS file and put it in `/boot/overlays`. The driver can do absolute x axis so you do not need to worry about losing interrupts. You need a Python event handler to catch x axis changes.